# Removing duplicate mark (?) In the URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL with a structure like this:

```
http://website.coy/user/profile.php?id=123
```

I created a different URL on `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user/profile/?id=$1
```

The result becomes:

```
http://website.coy/profile/123
```

The code above works pretty well. But there is a bit of a problem.

I redirected the page from `http://` to`https://`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

**But what happened?**

The browser displays a cluttered URL structure, like this:

```
https://website.coy/profile/123?id=123
```

How to fix this error in order to display the structure as:

```
https://website.coy/profile/123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must redirect to https before rewriting. Change the order of the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user/profile/?id=$1
```

Comment: Yes I just realized that I overturned the code. Thanks you